# Bootstrap navigation menu not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I am on a device with narrow screen. In this case the collapsed menu sometimes expands and some times does not. Here is the sequence of my footer

```
<script async="async" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script async="async" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my code for menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class=container style=width:100%>
<div class=navbar-header>
<a href class=navbar-brand>SiteName</a>
<button class=navbar-toggle type=button data-toggle=collapse data-target=#navbar-main>
<span class=icon-bar></span>
<span class=icon-bar></span>
<span class=icon-bar></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id=navbar-main>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href=url>Menu</a></li>
<li><a href=url>Menu</a></li>
<li><a href=url>Menu</a></li>
<li><a href=url style=color:black>Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have added this code snippet too in the footer

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();});</script>
```

On further inspection I found out that after the collpased menu button is click the html inside expanded menu should change to

```
<div style="" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="navbar-main">
```

from

```
<div style="height: 0.916667px;" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it using `CSS` @media anotation:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    // your needed style here
}
```

Also if you have different sizes / needs check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: What did you put in here?

Comment: I mean should it be something like :active { expand styles) };

Comment: For me problem is with the menu padding when screen is narrow, so I use  `padding-left: 0px;` to avoid that... you should check your needs with expand...